# Ignore wrapping class when serializing in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
[Serializable]
public class Matrix4
{
    private double[] m = new double[16];
}
```

This class will be serialized to:

```
{"m":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]}
```

However i wish to ignore the wrapping class Matrix4 and simply serialize the class to:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

The class is used in other classes that are serialized. I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer for serializing.

Comment: You want to `serialize` class to JSON, or you just want to get a `string` full of `double`s, which are separated by a comma?

Comment: This is just a simplified example of the Matrix4 class. It contains more methods and data for translation, rotation, invert. The class is used in other classes that is serialized. Using DataContractJsonSerializer for serializing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that but not with default JSON serializers, because `m` is a property and a very very vital information to reconstruct `Matrix4`.

Consider the scenario where `Matrix4` has another property say `n`, then without that information inside the JSON you won't be able to reconstruct it.

But, However if you really need something like that, then you have to serialize it with a custom serializer, you can either achieve them by sub-classing one, and then applying your own conversion codes or just simply serialize the `m` property, but not the full class. In this case one option would be to use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library -

```
var matrix = new Matrix4();
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matrix.m);
```

But, you should know that, the JSON you are trying to create is not a valid one based on the class `Matrix4`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you  misunderstood the concept of serialziation and you just need to create a string which represents the `m` object. For this, you can use:

```
class Matrix4
{
    private double[] m;

    public Matrix4(double [] pm)
    {
        this.m = pm;
    }

    public string GetStringRepresentation()
    {
        string _RetValue = "[";
        for(int i=0;i<this.m.Length;i++) 
        {
            _RetValue += this.m[i];
            if(this.m.Length != i)
            {
                _RetValue += ",";   
            }
        }
        _RetValue += "]";
        return _RetValue;
    }

    // your additional functions in here

}
```

After that, when you use

```
Matrix4 _Matrix = new Matrix4(new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 } );
string _Representation - _Matrix.GetStringRepresentation();
// _Representation = "[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]";
```

If you really want to serialize, you don't 'invent' your own format, you just let the compiler serialize / deserialize the object and don't care what does it contain.

Comment: Problem is that third party interfaces requires matrixes on the [1, 0, 1...] but I still would like to use my wrapper for Matrix and serilize it directly to the accepted format.

Comment: @Andreas Can you edit your question and specify the exact format  third-party interfaces need?

Comment: 1 and 0 are just there for demo purpose.